# rails acts_as_state_machine problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restful-authentication

I've installed the restful_authentication plugin.  I'm Using rails 2.2.2.  However, I can't seem to get past a certain error:

"undefined method acts_as_state_machine"

It doesn't matter if I call db:migrate or script/server, everything results in this same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `--stateful` or `--aasm` when you run the generator, it enables [`acts_as_state_machine`](http://github.com/rubyist/aasm/tree/master) support.  If that is behavior you want, try installing aasm from the above github link and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: I did use --stateful in generating.  The link you provided was what was needed.